# Can I use a 2d sequential CNN model for object detection or localization in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, object-detection

I have trained a 2d sequential CNN model in Keras on my dataset. The results that I have received are very good 97.5% accuracy which is much more than I require.

Now can I use this trained model for object detection or localization? if yes can you reference some documentation?

Comment: You need localization models like R-CNNs or YOLO for object localization.

Comment: can i create a localization model that finds the bounding boxes and then apply my classifier on the cropped image?

Comment: These are called object detection models and have a different architecture(though they use CNN layers). Look up those architectures like Faster R-CNN. YOLO, SSD etc. Also, your question ihas no info on which dataset you used and strange statement like "very good 97.5% accuracy which is much more than I require". Try to formulate questions in a more detailed way.

Comment: YOLO can do that for you.